# how to get 2 words with SUBSTRING in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

i have a column containing like this

```
Term
------- 
Semester Genap 2016/2017 
Semester Ganjil 2016/2017
```

i want to get

```
Term
------- 
Semester Genap 
Semester Ganjil
```

how to do it with SUBSTRING?

Comment: How would we know that it's 2016/2017 to knock off? Do you just want the first 2 words with spaces between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And one more approach, using a *string-split* approach via XML:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,Term VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('Semester Genap 2016/2017')
,('Semester Ganjil 2016/2017');

WITH Casted AS (
                SELECT ID
                      ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT Term AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS TheXML
                FROM @tbl
               )
SELECT ID 
      ,TheXML.value(N'(x/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part1
      ,TheXML.value(N'(x/text())[2]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part2
      ,TheXML.value(N'(x/text())[3]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part3
FROM Casted;
```

The result

```
ID  Part1       Part2   Part3
1   Semester    Genap   2016/2017
2   Semester    Ganjil  2016/2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always want everything to the left of a date, and the date starts with a "2", then this will work (Horrible, but works):

Just replace variable (used for testing only) with your column:

```
declare @String varchar(50) = 'Semester Genap 2016/2017'

select SUBSTRING(@String,0,len(@String)-(len(@String)-CHARINDEX('2',@String,0))-1)
```

Produces:
'Semester Genap'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `charindex` to find the spaces, and use that to get the first 2 words:

```
declare @t nvarchar(50);
set @t = 'Semester Genap 2016/2017';

select @t, CHARINDEX(' ', @t), SUBSTRING(@t, 0, charindex(' ', @t, charindex(' ',@t) + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of `SUBSTRING(@statement,0,CHARINDEX(@statement,' ',CHARINDEX(@statement,' ')+1))`. I don't have any way to test it right now, but it should get you in right direction.

1. `CHARINDEX(@statement,' ')` - start by finding first space (this ends first word
2. `CHARINDEX(@statement,' ',CHARINDEX(@statement,' ')+1)` - next find the next space, or rather find first space starting from right after first space (this marks end of second word)
3. `SUBSTRING(@statement,0,CHARINDEX(@statement,' ',CHARINDEX(@statement,' ')+1))` - get the substring starting from the beginning right to the second space.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant for the problem.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Semester Genap 2016/2017',1,LEN('Semester Genap 2016/2017') - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE('Semester Genap 2016/2017')))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your term perhaps includes old data like `199x/199x` then you could use `PATINDEX` to find the first number in your string.

```
DECLARE @Term varchar(max) = 'Semester Genap 2016/2017'

SELECT RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Term, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @Term +'0') - 1))
```